# WPF DataGrid Control:insert New Row

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

WPF : i have a grid which is bind from a List i want Insert a row before selected row.
i can do this via insert a new blank record into a List ad rebind my grid but problem is my grid not persist after this like some cell are disable before insert the new row but after insert the new row(rebind) all those cells are enable again.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), this allows you to add items in a non-disruptive manner since you do not need to rebind the grid at all.